# Choosing a sample based on where the density function is highest

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Is there a name for the following process?

Say I have an absolutely continuous probability density function $f$ with compact support, and I take $k$ independent samples $x_1,\dots,x_k$ from $f$.  Then, I let $x^*$ be the sample for which $f(x_i)$ is the largest, i.e. $x^* = \arg \max_i f(x_i)$.  My question is, is there a name for this process, and can anything be said about the distribution of $x^*$?  This basically has the effect of emphasizing the modes of $f$ more aggressively.

Comment: "Subsampled estimate of the mode."  But in your problem is $f$ known?  Otherwise, how would you compute $x^*$?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is known.  I'm interested in describing the distribution of $x^*$ in terms of $f$.

Comment: As $k\to\infty$, the distribution of $x^*$ will obviously be concentrated near the maximum of $f$ (assuming for simplicity that $f$ has a unique global max), as you already pointed out yourself. What else do you hope to be able to say in this generality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your $k$ samples are taken with replacement, then your method is a *Bootstrap estimate of the mode*.  In the limit of a large number of such samples, the Bootstrap estimate coincides with the true mode.

[Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) is useful when seeking the variance of a statistic such as the mode, as in your case.